# Search for avaliable library before #pragma comment in c++?

Tags: c++, c, linker, static-libraries

I have a piece of code which relies on the "Xinput.lib" file provided by windows in order to interface with a xbox controller.

Recently I installed VS2012 which seems to have caused "Xinput.lib" to no longer be available to the compiler. I found a workaround where I instead I use "Xinput9_1_0.lib" on the system running the VS2012 compiler. This however causes a problem since I am developing on multiple systems where one is running VS2012 and the other is running VS2010. To compile I have to change between "Xinput9_1_0.lib" and "Xinput.lib" within the code.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to search for the available library before using #pragma comment to link the library?

Something like this (I realize this is in no way valid, just a demonstration of intent):

```cpp
if("Xinput.lib" exists) {
#pragma comment(lib,"Xinput.lib")
}
else if("Xinput9_1_0.lib" exists) {
#pragma comment(lib,"Xinput9_1_0.lib")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the macro for the particular version of VS you're interested in to select the appropriate library:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER < 1700 //pre 2012
#pragma comment(lib,"Xinput.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib,"Xinput9_1_0.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: Even better would be to check the Windows SDK (Platform SDK) version, since VS2010 probably will also have `"Xinput9_1_0.lib"` when the latest SDK is installed.

Comment: Well I have tried intalling SDK7.1 on the computer without VS2012 and it still could not find '"Xinput9_1_0.lib"' therefore I think that it is just VS2012 that is messing everything up.

Comment: Did you mean `#if _MSC_VER < 1700`?